# map 100% reduce 0% in running hadoop word count

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I want to run hadoop word count on cluster from eclipse. But I get an error. I changed the directory for output, but there is no change in program behavior.
Can you help me solve this error:

```
     2013-10-23 23:06:13,783 WARN  [main] conf.Configuration  
(Configuration.java:warnOnceIfDeprecated(816)) - session.id is deprecated. Instead, use 
dfs.metrics.session-id
2013-10-23 23:06:13,794 INFO  [main] jvm.JvmMetrics (JvmMetrics.java:init(76)) -   
Initializing JVM Metrics with processName=JobTracker, sessionId=
2013-10-23 23:06:13,829 INFO  [main] jvm.JvmMetrics (JvmMetrics.java:init(71)) - Cannot 
initialize JVM Metrics with processName=JobTracker, sessionId= - already initialized
2013-10-23 23:06:13,915 WARN  [main] util.NativeCodeLoader (NativeCodeLoader.java:
<clinit>(62)) - Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using   
builtin-java classes where applicable
2013-10-23 23:06:13,947 WARN  [main] mapreduce.JobSubmitter 
(JobSubmitter.java:copyAndConfigureFiles(138)) - Hadoop command-line option parsing not 
performed. Implement the Tool interface and execute your application with ToolRunner to 
remedy this.
2013-10-23 23:06:13,962 WARN  [main] mapreduce.JobSubmitter 
(JobSubmitter.java:copyAndConfigureFiles(247)) - No job jar file set.  User classes may not be found. See Job or Job#setJar(String).
2013-10-23 23:06:13,978 WARN  [main] snappy.LoadSnappy (LoadSnappy.java:<clinit>(46)) - 
Snappy native library not loaded
2013-10-23 23:06:13,985 INFO  [main] mapred.FileInputFormat 
(FileInputFormat.java:listStatus(233)) - Total input paths to process : 1
2013-10-23 23:06:14,107 INFO  [main] mapreduce.JobSubmitter 
(JobSubmitter.java:submitJobInternal(368)) - number of splits:1
2013-10-23 23:06:14,167 WARN  [main] conf.Configuration 
(Configuration.java:warnOnceIfDeprecated(816)) - mapred.output.value.class is   
deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.output.value.class
2013-10-23 23:06:14,168 WARN  [main] conf.Configuration 
(Configuration.java:warnOnceIfDeprecated(816)) - mapred.job.name is deprecated. 
Instead, use mapreduce.job.name
2013-10-23 23:06:14,169 WARN  [main] conf.Configuration 
(Configuration.java:warnOnceIfDeprecated(816)) - mapred.input.dir is deprecated. 
Instead, use mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.inputdir
2013-10-23 23:06:14,169 WARN  [main] conf.Configuration 
(Configuration.java:warnOnceIfDeprecated(816)) - mapred.output.dir is deprecated. 
 Instead, use mapreduce.output.fileoutputformat.outputdir
2013-10-23 23:06:14,169 WARN  [main] conf.Configuration 
(Configuration.java:warnOnceIfDeprecated(816)) - mapred.map.tasks is deprecated. 
Instead, use mapreduce.job.maps
2013-10-23 23:06:14,170 WARN  [main] conf.Configuration 
(Configuration.java:warnOnceIfDeprecated(816)) - mapred
```

and MyHadoopDriver is:

```
package org.orzota.bookx.mappers;

import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Reducer;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextOutputFormat;

public class MyHadoopDriver {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JobClient client = new JobClient();
    JobConf conf = new JobConf(
            org.orzota.bookx.mappers.MyHadoopDriver.class);
    conf.setJobName("BookCrossing1.0");


    // TODO: specify output types
    conf.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    conf.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

    // TODO: specify a mapper
    conf.setMapperClass(org.orzota.bookx.mappers.MyHadoopMapper.class);

    // TODO: specify a reducer
    conf.setReducerClass(org.orzota.bookx.mappers.MyHadoopReducer.class);
    /////////////////////////////////////////////
    conf.setInputFormat(TextInputFormat.class);
    conf.setOutputFormat(TextOutputFormat.class);

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////
    FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(conf, new Path(args[0]));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(conf, new Path(args[1]));

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////
    client.setConf(conf);
    try {
        JobClient.runJob(conf);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

}
```

Comment: You need to show us some code, preferable your main where you set all the classes for the job.

Comment: There might also be a version conflict, since I see a lot of deprecation warnings. Which version of hadoop did you install and which wordcount code did you use, if they don't match you can have strange looking errors.

Comment: my hadoop version is 1.0.4 but i dont know the wordcount version..i thaught it is not important.

Comment: i confused. you mean i use new api? or my code is incorrect ? :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two FileOutputFormat classes in the Hadoop codebase, and you picked the deprecated one.

Everywhere you have "org.apache.hadoop.mapred", you should use "org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce".  I bet that will get you much closer to working.

Comment: Is that so, the JobClient class suggests that she is using the old API consistently I think. (the deprecatedness is not so important it will keep being supported) To see the differences between the two APIs she could have a look at:
http://www.slideshare.net/sh1mmer/upgrading-to-the-new-map-reduce-api
But I agree with you, if you can you should use the new API, I am not sure though that will solve all problems, on the other hand the logs contain only warnings and no errors.

Answer (score 0):

Can you give this one a try, this one is with the new API and very easy to understand.

[Wordcount example](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/WordCount) with the new API.

If you really want to stick to the old API have a look [here](http://kickstarthadoop.blogspot.be/2011/04/word-count-hadoop-map-reduce-example.html)
What is really important is that you use `Toolrunner.run(..)`to start the application, my guess is that you didn't, since your code is in the main function.